# How to parse LDAP Generalized Time in Java 8?

Tags: java, datetime, time, ldap, java-time

**Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): Syntaxes and Matching Rules** defines a [Generalized Time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-3.3.13) which has a seconds component that may be a leap-second.

There are more complications with the definition since the fractional component could refer to either be fractional hours, minutes or seconds depending on what is present.

I have tried various approaches using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` such as a `appendInstant`, `parseUnresolved`, and even a custom `TemporalField`.

The API for `DateTimeFormatter` takes/returns types written against the date/time abstractions but yet it doesn't seem to actually work with anything other than the standard implementations which is pretty disappointing.

Surely others have hit similar custom formats and I'd hope that these use cases were considered as part of JSR-310.

What are the options?

Is it possible to create a custom formatter which can reuse most of the existing ISO8601 parsing logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discussion of Java-8-approach:

**Handling of leap seconds**

I don't know if parsing leap seconds is really important for you (because it is rather an exotic feature which hardly happens in standard business applications), but I would not recommend to use the standard Java-8-API for doing it, see also the officially [documented limitations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedLeapSecond--):

> the handling of leap-seconds is limited to
>   DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendInstant()

So following intuitive approach fails (and does so for any other pattern):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART);
TemporalAccessor raw = dtf.parse("2016-12-31T23:59:60Z");
Instant instant = Instant.from(raw);
System.out.println(
    instant 
    + " (leap-second-parsed=" + raw.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond()) + ")");
```

Rather you have to do this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
TemporalAccessor raw = dtf.parse("2016-12-31T23:59:60Z");
Instant instant = Instant.from(raw);
System.out.println(
    instant
    + " (leap-second-parsed=" + raw.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond()) + ")");
// 2016-12-31T23:59:59Z (leap-second-parsed=true)
```

However, it fails for an input with timezone offset not equal to zero, and the **code does not validate due to internal lack of leap second data** if the input is really a true leap second, for example it says that "`2015-05-01T23:59:60Z`" is a leap second (but we know better it is not such one).

**Handling of decimal hours and minutes**

The suggested solution given by S. Colebourne (the author of java.time-API) is flawed. Using `appendFraction()` suffers from handling only ONE element but handling of decimal parts requires to handle the specified element AND all other elements with higher precision. See first the printing example (based on the code of the proposal):

```
    DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0, 6, true)
        .appendOffsetId()
        .toFormatter();
    OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.of(2017, 3, 21, 5, 28, 59, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(dt); // 2017-03-21T05:28:59Z
    System.out.println(dt.format(f)); // 2017-03-21 05.466666Z

    OffsetDateTime dt2 = OffsetDateTime.of(2017, 3, 21, 5, 28, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(dt2); // 2017-03-21T05:28Z
    System.out.println(dt2.format(f)); // 2017-03-21 05.466666Z
```

We see that two different `OffsetDateTime`-values result in the same decimal hour which is obviously wrong. The difference was just a delta in the field `SECOND_OF_MINUTE` (not taken into account by `appendFraction()`).

What about parsing? We can observe the same effect in reverse which makes the whole approach unusable.

Let the input to be parsed "2017-03-01 13.52Z" as given in the proposal as example. The observed parsed value is: `2017-03-01T13:31Z` But this result is NOT correct. It should be: `2017-03-01T13:31.2Z` or `2017-03-01T13:31:12Z` (explanation: 0.52 x 60 = 31.2 => minute component and 0.2 * 60 = 12 => second component).

**Conclusion: Don't use the standard API for handling decimal values of time-related elements. There is no support by design.** I say even "by design" because all fields finally work with a long-primitive (as value type) which is not suitable to incorporate decimal values based on several fields.

---

What to do else? I have set up [my own library](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) to fill gaps in the java.time-API like described above.

### Time4J-solution (v4.25 or later):

I suggest you to use following code in order to model the LDAP-specification. It is rather complex but this is necessary due to the complexity of the specification itself.

```
ChronoFormatter<PlainDate> df =
    ChronoFormatter.setUp(PlainDate.axis(), Locale.ROOT)
        .addFixedInteger(PlainDate.YEAR, 4)
        .addFixedInteger(PlainDate.MONTH_AS_NUMBER, 2)
        .addFixedInteger(PlainDate.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .build();
ChronoFormatter<Moment> mf =
    ChronoFormatter.setUp(Moment.axis(), Locale.US) // US for preference of dot in decimal elements
        .addCustomized(PlainDate.COMPONENT, df)
        .addFixedInteger(PlainTime.DIGITAL_HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
        .startOptionalSection()
        .addFixedInteger(PlainTime.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .startOptionalSection()
        .addFixedInteger(PlainTime.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .startOptionalSection()
        .addLiteral('.', ',')
        .addFraction(PlainTime.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, false)
        .endSection()
        .endSection()
        .endSection()
        .addTimezoneOffset(DisplayMode.SHORT, false, Collections.singletonList("Z"))
        .or()
        .addCustomized(PlainDate.COMPONENT, df)
        .addFixedInteger(PlainTime.DIGITAL_HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
        .addFixedDecimal(PlainTime.DECIMAL_MINUTE)
        .addTimezoneOffset(DisplayMode.SHORT, false, Collections.singletonList("Z"))
        .or()
        .addCustomized(PlainDate.COMPONENT, df)
        .addFixedDecimal(PlainTime.DECIMAL_HOUR)
        .addTimezoneOffset(DisplayMode.SHORT, false, Collections.singletonList("Z"))
        .build();
assertThat(
    mf.parse("199412160532-0500").toString(),
    is("1994-12-16T10:32:00Z"));
assertThat(
    mf.parse("199412160532Z").toString(),
    is("1994-12-16T05:32:00Z"));
assertThat(
    mf.parse("20161231185960.123456789-0500").toString(),
    is("2016-12-31T23:59:60,123456789Z"));
assertThat(
    mf.parse("201612311859.25-0500").toString(),
    is("2016-12-31T23:59:15Z"));
assertThat(
    mf.parse("2016123118.25-0500").toString(),
    is("2016-12-31T23:15:00Z"));
```

As you can see, the code does handle leap seconds (even with non-zero offsets). Time4J also validates leap seconds because it manages its independent leap second data (for example extracted from IANA-TZDB). And a leap second is stored within an object of type `Moment`. This type is the counterpart to `java.time.Instant`. A [conversion between both types](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/TemporalType.html#INSTANT) is trivial (or directly via the method `moment.toTemporalAccessor()`). Just to note: The leap second itself will be lost during such a conversion. If you just want to ignore the leap second i.e. handle it like the last second before then either just go with the conversion to `Instant` or work with standard POSIX-related methods in `Moment` (and the conversion to any "local" types like `PlainTimestamp/LocalDateTime` etc. also looses the leap second).

Decimal values are also supported because the interface `ChronoElement` (as counterpart to `TemporalField`) is generified and based on an object value type, not a long-primitive, see for example the element for the [decimal minute](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainTime.html#DECIMAL_MINUTE) which uses the value type `BigDecimal`.

Finally parsing dots or commas is possible (as required by the LDAP-specification). This is a detail which is also not supported by Java-8, for comparison see the [JDK-issue 8163932](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163932).

Answer (score 2):

This code parses fractional hours. It can be adjusted for fractional days:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH")
    .appendFraction(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0, 6, true)
    .appendOffsetId()
    .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dt.format(f));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-03-01 13.52Z", f));
```

This code can be used to find a leap second:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
String text = "2017-03-01T23:59:60";
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
TemporalAccessor accessor = fmt.parseUnresolved(text, pp);
if (pp.getErrorIndex() >= 0) {
  throw new DateTimeParseException("Parse error", text, pp.getErrorIndex());
}
if (accessor.getLong(SECOND_OF_MINUTE) == 60) {
  System.out.println("Leap second");
} else {
  System.out.println("Not a leap second");
}
```

The time library is very extensible. There are implementations at [ThreeTen-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) which show what can be done in terms of alternate date-time classes like [`YearQuarter`](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.java#L76) and alternative fields like [`PackedFields`](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/extra/PackedFields.java#L58).

---

Update:

It is worth noting for posterity that the complexity here comes from the need to support fractional minutes, hours and days. When parsing a standard `Instant`, leap seconds are just ignored by default.

Comment: What can we do once a leap second has been found? Assuming I just want to treat 60 the same as 59. I suppose I could wrap the `TemporalAccessor` and handle the `SECOND_OF_MINUTE` as a special case and then use `ZonedDateTime.from`. All seems ok but it does seem a little odd to create a `DateTimeFormatter` but yet not be able to use `ZonedDateTime.parse`.

Comment: You can use `formatter.withResolverStyle(LENIENT)` with the standard `parse` method. What will happen is that 23:59:60 will be treated as 00:00 on the following date, so you'd need to subtract one second.